Why is component re-rendering when state is remaining same and strict mode is off?
I am using REACT 18.3.1
When I click on increment button the component re renders (indicated by the log statement), which is expected since the state changes from 0 to 1. But when I click on the increment button again the component re renders again ( indicated by log statement ), but the state is already 1 and does not change. After that the component does not re-render when I click on increment button again. I am not using strict mode. And I also tried it in production mode after creating a build of the project.
Here is my App.js file
import './App.css';
import React, {useMemo, useState} from "react";

function App() {
    const [num, setNum] = useState(0);
    console.log('rendering outside APP....')
    console.log(num)

    return (
        <>
            <h1>{num}</h1>
            <button onClick={() => setNum(1)}>Increment</button>
        </>
    );
}

export default App;



Here is my index.js file
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
    <>
        <App/>
    </>
);


Here is the console output of the situationSample output
